# Name for time period between boot and shutdown (login/logout is to "session" like boot/shutdown is to ???)

Tags: terminology

The time between login and logout is called a "user session", "login session" or simply "session". Is there a similar specific name for an OS "session", i.e. the period of time between boot and shutdown? "One uptime" is the only thing that comes to my mind, but that seems weird. Can it be used that way? Is there a better term?

Examples:

- *The NTP sync and the log entry ocurred during the same **?????**.*
  (meaning "the system was not rebooted between the NTP sync and the log entry")
- *During one **?????**, the uptime value increases monotonically over time.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were nearly there yourself - I'd call this an "uptime cycle" if I were so inclined to name it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *"system uptime"*, *"uptime period"*, *"uptime cycle"* so as not to repeat yourself, e.g.:

- *The NTP sync and the log entry occurred during the same uptime period.*
- *The uptime value increases monotonically over time during an uptime cycle.*
- *Dynamic detection is performed during system uptime*